# Pandas Dataframe Color Styling based on NaN Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colors, nan

I currently have a pandas dataframe that has four columns and is structured below accordingly.

```
| Date        | Transaction ID | Amount 1 | Amount 2 
| Nov-10-2021 | ABC123         | 100.20   | nan
| Dec-10-2021 | DEF456         | nan      | 30.21
| Dec-13-2021 | GHI789         | 341.88   | nan
| Dec-18-2021 | JKL101         | nan      | 122.3
```

As you can see, this is a dataframe of transactions. I want to color the transaction rows that are considered "income" as "yellow" and those that are "expenses" as "green". To do so, if amount 1 is nan, then the row is an income row, and otherwise, it'd be an expense. I tried the following after reading up the pandas color styling documentation and other Stack Overflow posts:

```
def yellow_or_green(dataframe):
    if (pd.isna(dataframe["Amount 1"])):
        color = "yellow"
    else:
        color = "green"
    return "color: %s" % color

df1.style.applymap(yellow_or_green)
```

Then, after displaying the dataframe, it remains unchanged. I'm not sure why it's not working, your help and guidance are appreciated.

Comment: Do you need rows? Or values in `Transaction ID` ? Or in ` Amount 1` ?

Comment: I need the rows to be colored yellow if "Amount 1" is nan and colored green otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['Nov-10-2021', 'Dec-10-2021', 'Dec-13-2021', 'Dec-18-2021'], 
                   'Transaction ID': ['ABC123', 'DEF456', 'GHI789', 'JKL101'], 
                   'Amount 1': [100.2, np.nan, 341.88, np.nan],
                   'Amount 2': [ np.nan, 30.21,  np.nan, 122.3]})
    

print (df)

          Date Transaction ID  Amount 1  Amount 2
0  Nov-10-2021         ABC123    100.20       NaN
1  Dec-10-2021         DEF456       NaN     30.21
2  Dec-13-2021         GHI789    341.88       NaN
3  Dec-18-2021         JKL101       NaN    122.30

print (df.columns.tolist())
['Date', 'Transaction ID', 'Amount 1', 'Amount 2']
```

---

```
def yellow_or_green(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    c2 = 'background-color: green'
    # condition
    m = x["Amount 1"].isna()
    # DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c1, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)

    # set columns by condition
    return df1.mask(m, c2)

#if not working convert to numeric
df["Amount 1"] = df["Amount 1"].astype(float)
#then try convert with NaNs for non parseable values
df["Amount 1"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Amount 1"], errors='coerce')

df.style.apply(yellow_or_green, axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

If need colored only some columns:

```
def yellow_or_green(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
    c2 = 'background-color: green'
    # condition
    m = x["Amount 1"].isna()
    # DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df1.loc[:, ['Date','Transaction ID']] = np.where(m.to_numpy()[:, None], c1, c2)
    # set columns by condition
    return df1

df.style.apply(yellow_or_green, axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I tried the code, but it looks like the dataframe is still unchanged/uncolored. I'm not sure why...

Comment: @MAGEPAC - Can you try `df["Amount 1"] = df["Amount 1"].astype(float)` ?

Comment: Hmm, it gives me an error that says KeyError: Amount 1. Here's the error screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/z2Da2KB

Comment: @MAGEPAC - What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Where do you see this?

Comment: @MAGEPAC - error menas there is no column `Amount 1`, so I ask what is real columns names by test `print (df.columns.tolist())` before  my solution.

Comment: I see. This is what I get:
['Date', 'Transaction ID', 'Amount 1', 'Amount 2']

Comment: @MAGEPAC - for me working well, added DataFrame to answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I was using dataframe that's called "df1" rather than "df" so there was a typo in one of the lines which was why I was getting the error lol. Now, after I run the code, it doesn't give me any errors, but the dataframe is still uncolored when I use "df1.style"

Comment: @MAGEPAC - do you try `.to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')` ?

Comment: It worked as an excel file! Not sure why displaying it using df.style doesn't show the colors, but as an excel file, it shows the colors lol, thanks a lot!